# changing ckeditor dimension for different instances (not all instances)

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dimensions

i'm trying to change dimensions for multiple ckeditor in the same page using this code just after the textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.config.width ='250px';
CKEDITOR.config.height='600px';
</script>
```

it changes all instances in the page and i know how to adjust default values in the config.js but i'm trying to change dimensions for some instances not all of them

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I have the same question, found an easy workaround but not sure it's the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11124182/how-to-set-up-ckeditor-for-multiple-instances-with-different-heights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever need to change the height of specific instance of CKEditor and all you can change is `config.js`, then you can use `this.name` inside configuration file to detect the right instance of the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Default height for all instances
    config.height = '400';

    // Height for specific instance, the ID of textarea is "editor1"
    if (this.name == 'editor1') {
        config.height = '200';
    }
};
```